# React - Can't import modules if entry points have timestamp in file name

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have module-a which has the following directory structure

```
module-a
   public/index.html
   src/index.js
```

index.js exports component **App**.

module-a built through webpack, for caching related issues the build output file names are appended with timestamp, for example the dist for this module would be

```
module-a
   index.[timestamp].html
   index.[timestamp].js
```

module-b has a dependency of module-a, when I try to import App component of module-a, I'm getting module not found error.

```
import App from module-a (not working)
```

```
import App from module-a/index.[timestamp] (working)
```

If I remove the timestamp in the filename the modules, I could import components with just module name.

The timestamp will change for every build, so I can't hardcode the timestamp in the import statements.

My question is how can I import App component without specifying the index.[timestamp] in module-b.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try `import * as App from module-a` ??

Comment: I'm getting ```ENOENT: no such file or directory``` it is expecting a ```index.js``` file